# How do read and loop through these MySQLi results?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-mysqlidb

I'm currently converting some code from mysql to mysqli. I have downloaded this class:
https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

I am trying something as simple as this:

```
    $params = array('handset');
    $rs = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT Id FROM productrates WHERE Type = ? ORDER BY GrossYearly ASC LIMIT 0,1 ", $params);   
    print_r($rs);
```

That prints out:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id] => 100017 ) )

When not using this class, I was using the following code afterwards:

```
        if ($rs->num_rows != 0) {
        $row = $rs->fetch_assoc();
```

However that now generates error:

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

So the results are coming back in an array - how do I read how many results came back and then loop through them? I know this must be simple but I've managed to really confuse myself and time I need a quick solution.

Further information - here is rawQuery:

```
public function rawQuery($query, $bindParams = NULL) 
{
    $this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $stmt = $this->_prepareQuery();

    if (gettype($bindParams) === 'array') {
        $params = array('');        // Create the empty 0 index
        foreach ($bindParams as $prop => $val) {
            $params[0] .= $this->_determineType($val);
            array_push($params, $bindParams[$prop]);
        }

                call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),$this->refValues($params));

    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $this->reset();

    $results = $this->_dynamicBindResults($stmt);
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($rs) {
    $row = $rs[0];
}
```

but better download this one: https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql
it will take you only 2 lines to get your $id

```
$sql = "SELECT Id FROM productrates WHERE Type = ?s ORDER BY GrossYearly LIMIT 1";
$id  = $this->db->getOne($sql, 'handset');
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks! How would you go about checking an empty recordset? Just: 

    if (count($rs) == 0)

Comment: `if (count($rs) == 0)`  is equal to `if ($rs)` in PHP

Comment: Cool thanks! I literally just needed a class like this which is more secure than mysql and easy to work with. I think this will do!

Comment: Yup, that'e exactly what it is: very easy to use and way more secure than any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns an array into an array :) 
So to display the first one :

```
$FirstArray = $rs[0];
```

To display all the items in this array :

```
foreach ($FirstArray as $result)
    echo $result;
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

There is no active development in PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class.
I dont think you should waste your time..
Anyway, it is left to you.

Comment: I don't think I need active development. I just need the simple stuff working and if I need to add anything to the class over time I can.

Comment: Is there a MySQLi class or similar you recommend then? I feel like now is the time to update ALL my mysql code and secure my pages more